# Unzipping files in WP8.1 Using SharpZipper

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use SharpZip.unzipper for my windows phone 8.1. However it is not reading some of the code. Since i am fairly new to windows phone development please let me know the alternatives of following code for WP8.1

```
using System.Windows.Resources;

public Stream GetFileStream(string filename)
        {
            if (fileEntries == null)
                fileEntries = ParseCentralDirectory(); //We need to do this in case the zip is in a format Silverligth doesn't like
            long position = this.stream.Position;
            this.stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Uri fileUri = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
            StreamResourceInfo info = new StreamResourceInfo(this.stream, null);
            StreamResourceInfo stream = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(info, fileUri);
            this.stream.Position = position;
            if (stream != null)
                return stream.Stream;
            return null;
        }
```

`Windows.Resources` seems missing
I can't call `StreamResourceInfo, System.Windows.Application`

I have tried using `App`. but there is no function for `GetResourceSteam`

I am not sure what to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few differences between WP8.1 runtime and WP8.1 Silverlight.

The code sample that you have will run on WP8.0 SL and WP8.1 SL.

It looks like you created a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime project.  There is no `System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream()`

---

Either convert it to a compatible 8.1 runtime stream or recreate your project to target Silverlight instead.

---

```C#
// sample
private async void ZipLibraryTest()
{
    // create the full path
    string zip = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "filename.zip");

    // create the storage file with the file name
    StorageFile sf = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(zip);

    // create the IO Stream
    using (System.IO.Stream output = await sf.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        // open the zip file for writing, use the stream from the file
        ZipFile zf = ZipFile.Create(output);

        // rest of your code
        // ...
        // ...

        // close the zip file
        zf.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i am relatively new. Can you guide me how to do this and what impact will it have on my Windows universal app? I am using 2013 Visual Studio.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar if you're using an universal app, it's definitely not silver light, so it's WP8.1 runtime.  You want to use a System.IO.Stream to do your bidding.  I updated the solution to get you started, but the rest of the code you should be able to complete with some searching on MSDN or SO.